# How to create a dynamic road-like path in Angular?

Tags: angular, mobile

this is my first question on here, so please excuse me if I forget something! I am currently working on a side project to learn Angular and need help figuring out how to create a specific component. Here is a picture example of what it should look like:
[Dynamic path example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbS0n.png)

This should be responsive to the amount of items along the track, so I can't just use an image sadly. Does anyone know of a place I could start to accomplish this effect? Thanks :).

I actually have no idea where to start with this, but I know that I cannot use static things like an image to accomplish this. I have thought about SVG drawing, but I have never used this before. I am willing to learn though.

Answer (score 0):

Hey it's really an interesting question :) Here's how I'd go about doing it:

1. As far as I understand, the final UI will actually be a stack of elements that have an image, a curved line, a 'location' icon/point, and possibly something else (that's not on the img in example, but can possibly be added, like some textual data).
2. Having that in mind, each odd or even (depending on your choice of the starting point) will have everything placed in the opposite: a curved line will have opposite 'center', image will be on the opposite side etc.
3. So I'd start with creating an individual component as a placeholder for these elemenets, then use some iterator to display each on top of the other in another (wrapper) component, based on the data at hand (how many 'stops' there are, which images to send to individual components, which 'direction' to use etc.).
4. Then I'll take some online generator of canvas content (bezier curve especially, like https://www.victoriakirst.com/beziertool/ or similar) to generate the curves I need, take the code and tweak it to suit my UI needs - setting the colours, stroke/border thickness, angles etc.
5. Create or download some free svg icons to use as 'position' icons (different types, like an icon for 'start', 'finished', 'in progress' etc. depending on your needs).
6. The wrapper component (displaying full path) will send data (via @Input or @BehaviourSubject, or whatever suits your case more) to individual components in the loop (each displaying one step), so I'll use that data to toggle the 'side' on which the bezier curve is 'facing', where the img is positioned etc.
7. Additionally, you can create special conditions for the first/last 'position' - like different curve's start/end, position of the icon etc.

I hope this helps. Good luck!